# Trace of the product of a matrix and its complex conjugate transpose

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a Complex Matrix $A$ which is $n \times n$. How would I go about showing that $A^*A$ is $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n | a_{ij} |^2$$

Here $A^*$ refers to the complex conjugate - transpose of $A$.  I know that the trace of any  $n \times n$ matrix is defined to be $$\sum _{i = 1}^n a_{ii}$$

Comment: If you know what elements of $A^*$ look like, start by writing out diagonal elements of $A^* A$, by definition of matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that the trace of any square matrix $A$ is the sum of its diagonal entries. Also, in order to obtain the $(i,i)$ entry of $A^*A$ we need to multiply the $i$-th row of $A^*$ with the $i$-th column of $A$, right?

So, if the $i$-th column of $A$ looks like

\begin{pmatrix} a_{1i} \\ a_{2i} \\ \vdots \\ a_{ni} \end{pmatrix}

then the $i$-th row of $A^*$ is

$$\big( \begin{matrix}
\overline{a_{1i}} & \overline{a_{2i}} & \cdots & \overline{a_{ni}}
\end{matrix} \big)$$

and hence the $(i,i)$ entry of $A^*A$ is simply

$$\big( \begin{matrix}
\overline{a_{1i}} & \overline{a_{2i}} & \cdots & \overline{a_{ni}}
\end{matrix} \big)
\begin{pmatrix} a_{1i} \\ a_{2i} \\ \vdots \\ a_{ni} \end{pmatrix}
= \sum_{j=1}^n \overline{a_{ji}}a_{ji} = \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ji}|^2.
$$

Therefore, the trace of $A^*A$ is the sum of those entries from $i=1$ to $n$, that is,

$$\operatorname{tr}(A^*A) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ji}|^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

1. Find coefficients for a product $AB=C$ of two matrices $c_{ij} = \sum a_{ik}b_{kj}$
2. use your trace formula to get a trace formula for the product $BC$
3. Find coefficients of $A^*$ in terms of coefficients of $A$ and plug in for $B$